# Equivalent to pry / irb 's _ , but in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop, pry

I'm very familiar with the Ruby REPL's, irb and pry. In both, if I type something and forget to save it to a variable, I can access the last outputted thing by typing `_`

For example, in irb,

```
>> [2,3,4]
=> [2, 3, 4]
>> _
=> [2, 3, 4]
>>
```

In pry,

```
[1] pry(main)> [2,3,4]
=> [2, 3, 4]
[2] pry(main)> _
=> [2, 3, 4]
[3] pry(main)>
```

My question is, does a similar thing exist in Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features):

> The special variable `_` (underscore) contains the result of the last expression.

Comment: Wow, stupid question on my part... haha I had tested it when the last output was `undefined` , so I thought it wasn't a real thing.

Thanks for revealing the obvious answer! :p